# Stop indexing certain images

Tags: php, html, google-image-search, noindex

So I have a robots.txt file which contains:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
```

At most, it stops the indexing of a lot of images. However, I also have affiliate images that when you search come up in results in Google (and assumably other search engines too).

I was wondering if it was possible (I've searched with no results) to add a `rel="noindex"` to images, or equivalent.

The affiliate images are served through a PHP loop, so I was looking for a one line fix if possible, as well as knowing that I wouldn't have to manually add the code each time :)

Comment: Are serving the images via PHP?

Comment: Put the affiliate images in a folder called `/affiliate-images/` or whatever you want to name it then do `Disallow: /affiliate-images/`

Comment: @JohnConde yes the images are being served via PHP.

Comment: @crypticツ forgot to mention the images are served from the affiliates themselves not in my FTP.

Comment: Can you post some example SRC paths to the images?

Comment: @crypticツ this is one example: http://www.yceml.net/0356/11091300-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the images are being served via PHP you can easily tell Google not to index them by sending a HTTP header designed specifically for this purpose.

Just put this line before your image output:

```
header("X-robots-tag: noindex");
```

Comment: I had no idea you can control bots through headers as well. This is a great tip.

Answer (score 2):

add images that you dont want to be indexed in some folder, like dontindex, then add:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /dontindex/
```

This tells the robots not to include the contents in the `dontindex` directory. If you keep your images in a different directory, change that to whatever the name of the directory is where you keep your images.

So next time Google crawls your site, it sees this directive and drops your image from search results.
See: [Prevent Images from being Indexed](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35308)

Comment: I cant add a folder to the robots since the images are being served from the affiliates themselves not from my servers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell google, or any search engine for that matter, not to index images that are not coming from your domain.

Comment: I understand that, but clicking the image in google takes me to my website rather than the image link.